# Use an id from .append

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a little problem with some jQuery Code...

First, I have this code that works great :

```
    $(".add_cheque").click(function() {
        nb_cheque += 1;
        var html = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td><input type="text" name="montant'+nb_cheque+'" id="montant" value="Montant" /></td>';
        $('#services_pack').append(html);
    });
```

So now, I want to use the "montant" selector from the text input added to the page, with the keyup function... but it's not working...
If I do something like :

```
$('#montant').keyup(function() {
        alert('test keyup');
    });
```

And I type something in the `#montant` input, nothing is happening...

Anyone ?

Comment: You'll need delegation, as answers below point out, but you also need to give each input a unique ID - you can't keep using the same one.  Give it the same ID as the name (so it's unique) and give it a class name to attach the event handler to, rather than the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to have this event triggered after the #montant is added to the DOM

```
$(".add_cheque").click(function() {
    nb_cheque += 1;
    var html = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>'
      + '<td><input id="montant' + nb_cheque +'" type="text"' // unique ID
      + 'name="montant'+nb_cheque+'" id="montant" value="Montant" /></td>';
    $('#services_pack').append(html);


    // Here
    $('#montant' + nb_cheque).keyup(function() {
       alert('test keyup');
    });
});
```

**Or** you could set up a live(.on/.delegate/.live/etc) event keypress

Comment: hmmm.... what about a second time of click .add_cheque? a second element wiht id montant will be created...

Comment: As said just below this answer, I'll change my code to have unique id's. :)

Comment: Ah yes you'd just want to move that `+nb_cheque+` to the ID

Answer (score 1):

every time ou click on add_cheque you create a new row and button.. every button becomes #monant as id... but a dom id have to be unique...

you have to close your  also

try to create your button with a jquery object like this

```
var newButton = jQuery('<input type="text" name="montant'+nb_cheque+'" value="Montant" />');

var jRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td><td></td></tr>';

//add your button
jRow.find('td:last').append(newButton);

jQuery('#services_pack').append(jRow);

newButton.keyUp(function(){
    //your method
});
```

Comment: I'll consider adding unique id's to my inputs, thanks for your complete response ! :)